# Target class [Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-jetstream, laravel-permission

I hope you’re all right. I was wondering if you could take a look at a problem I’ve encountered in a Laravel project that uses Spatie Laravel Permission.

The mistake I’m facing is this:

Target class [Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware] does not exist.

I have reviewed the documentation and tried some common solutions, but so far I have had no luck in finding a solution.

I very much appreciate any suggestions or ideas you may have.

Thanks in advance for your help!

spatie/laravel-permission 6.0
Laravel Framework 10.29.0
PHP 8.2.11
laravel/jetstream 4.0
livewire/livewire 3.0

Comment: What did you try? What does the 'app/Http/Kernel.php' file look like?

Comment: Add inside " app/Http/Kernel.php" of package RoleMiddleware, PermissionMiddleware and RoleOrPermissionMiddleware uses protected $middlewareAliases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note: Make Middleware instead of Middlewares in the Path**

I was also facing the same issue when I install this package but I found a Solution that could may help you

In the documentation there could be like in the kernal.php file

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
    'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware::class,
    'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,
];
```

You can use this in the kernal.php file

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
    'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\PermissionMiddleware::class,
    'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,
];
```

Comment: I was facing the issue and after changing as per this, working fine now.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when I upgraded Spatie's package `laravel-permission` from version 3 to 6. I followed the [v6 upgrade guide](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v6/upgrading#content-upgrading-from-v5-to-v6) and found the solution.

The guide says that the `\Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\` namespace has been changed to `\Spatie\Permission\Middleware\` (singular). So, I had to update any references to the middleware classes in my `/app/Http/Kernel.php`.

Here is how my `/app/Http/Kernel.php` file looked before and after the update:

**Before:** (Notice Middlewares being plural)

```php
'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware::class,
'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,
```

**After:** (Notice Middleware being singular)

```php
'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\RoleMiddleware::class,
'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\PermissionMiddleware::class,
'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middleware\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,
```

This fixed the issue for me. I hope this helps you too.